# How to make data appear on Kura Web UI?

Tags: java, user-interface, kura

I've made most of the Kura examples present on its documentation (http://eclipse.github.io/kura/doc/intro.html), but now I need to make the opposite of what's shown on them: send data to Kura instead of from it.

I want to send data (in this case, Strings) to Kura and them make them appear on Kura Web UI (maybe using some sort of configurable application, if I had to guess).

I searched, but there's next to zero information on Kura Web UI. Most of the doubt surounding it is just how to get it up and running.

Is there any way to do this? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kura web UI is meant to be an administrative console for managing the Kura framework. It was never meant to be used to display data. If this is something you need, I would recommend creating a simple web app that can be run within the framework using the OSGi HttpService.

--Dave